# Distinguish notes FFT algorithm

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft

What I am trying to achieve is distinguishing separate notes in an audio file. For simplicity lets say that a couple of notes are played one after another. The main question is how to determine when the next note is played ?
What I have already done is reading samples from an audio file and doing Fourier Transform on those samples using JTransforms library. Here's what I get:
[image: piano note E].
Then I have calculated spectrum based on the data that FFT returned, and here's what I get:
[image: piano note E].
As I understand the bigger "columns" on the chart are the harmonics, and the small ones are noise and other non-harmonic overtones, right ?

After that I have tried to do same process with audio file with two notes played one after another, but the result was kind of the same.

As a side question, do any of you know some lightweight and fast libraries for visualizing such data ? Because using JFreeChart for bigger datasets is a real pain for my processor.

Comment: If you want to identify musical notes then you need to perform [**pitch detection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm). Note that pitch is not the same thing as frequency. It's not even the same thing as the frequency of the fundamental component (f0). Read up on Harmonic Product Spectrum, which is a popular method for pitch detection.

Comment: I believe this is related to signal processing.

I think you need to apply filters (as in band pass filters to check if a frequency is present in the signal). Basically use band pass filter to check for A,B,C,D, etc...

Using FFT there's no way to know if a specific note was played before another (at least to my knowledge) since it is frequency based.

Maybe you can try checking a signal (applying FFT) until you find a note using (band-pass filter) and after that take another time sample applying the same method.

Don't know if this will be computationally costly or not.

Comment: @PaulR I have seen a lot of your posts about signal processing here on stackoverflow, do you happen to have some kind of a blog if you ever decided to share your researches in this field ? Can I get in touch with you via something else than stackoverflow ? I am currently working on a huge project, which has many sub-projects involving pitch recognition, speech recognition an neural networks and reading up some chunks of information on the internet is not really helpful.

Comment: Best place to head to is http://dsp.stackexchange.com - it's much quieter than StackOverflow but the S/N ratio is very good and there are people there who know a lot more than I do about DSP (I also hang out there too of course),

Comment: Here are some of my blog post on the topic of pitch estimation: http://www.musingpaw.com/2012/04/musical-pitch-is-not-just-fft-frequency.html  and on frequency estimation: http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html#1

Comment: There have been many questions along these lines *pitch detection using FFT*.  Searching for them - and their answers is probably a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

To detect successive frequency bursts of different frequencies, and some of their time domain parameters, one can use overlapping short FFT windows (length shorter than the expected burst length) and look for where the relative magnitudes of frequency peaks swap order, or fall above/below thresholds.  If you know, a priori, the frequencies involved, you can use the Goertzel filters instead of FFTs, with sliding windows or successive approximation in time for finer time domain granularity.

For pitched notes (such as music), one can do something similar, except using a pitch detection/estimation method (instead of simple FFT magnitudes, which are not reliable) on sufficiently short time domain windows of data.

Comment: what do you mean by saying _expected burst length_ ? The length of a array with samples or time (e.g. seconds) ?
Btw, Goertzel filters are not quite good for my case, because I'm trying to find the frequencies **and** when those frequencies occure.

Comment: The length of the window affects the time frequency resolution trade-off.  Thus shorter/smaller time resolution (in either seconds or samples, as required for shorter tones) requires shorter windows.  A windowed Goertzel filter is identical to a windowed FFT (1 bin, for the same window length).